# Generate Xpath from parsed HTML with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, web-scraping

Given the following example HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFE4D8" valign="top">
    <td>in the next 20 minutes you will learn how to create a winter landscape. For this excersize you do need to have only a basic experience in Lightwave, so lets just start with it.<br>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How could I auto generate an Xpath expression to the tag that contains "20 minutes"; in the same manner that [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) does. Is this possible to do from within Ruby?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to generate an XPath expression given a string?

Comment: I want to generate an Xpath expression to an element that matches a certain criteria.

Comment: The bigger question is, why do you want/need to build a specific XPath? Why wouldn't `//*[contains(text(),'20 minutes')]` work for you?

Comment: I am creating a spider that will be able to determine the underlying CMS of a site. It should save the found Xpath and compare it with other matches in order to find similarities between systems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is not broken into different tags, you could find the lowest leaf node by

```
//*[contains(text(),'20 minutes')]
```

You can then generate the string of parents by adding `/..` at the end of the XPath until you got the root element `html`. At every step you will also need to get the position of the element by

```
//*[contains(text(),'20 minutes')]/position()
```

and for higher elements

```
//*[contains(text(),'20 minutes')]/../position()
```

After you know each tag name and position, you can build the path

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[x]/table[y]/tbody[z]/tr[1]/td[1]
```

With x, y, z being placeholders.

Since I don't know ruby, I cannot provide source code, but this will be an easy algorithm. The good thing is that you can implement this with any DOM parser, that knows XPath. It may be possible to optimize it considerably, if the DOM parser has a method for returning the parent of a node, because selecting the parent in XPath on its own for every step is slow and not viable for many/long documents.

It looks like [REXML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Node.html) for ruby support the `parent()` method.

Comment: Although this Xpath navigation is working, it is not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Then, what were you looking for? Some other path format or working code just waiting to plug it in?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build xpath with the [jini](https://rubygems.org/gems/jini) library yourself.

```
xpath = Jini.new('parent')
            .add_path('child')
            .add_attr('key', 'value)
            .to_s
puts xpath // parent/child[@key="value"]
```